# Is there a function that can output an image?

Tags: theming, media

```
[field_img] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [fid] => 200
    [list] => 1
    [data] => Array(
      [alt] => 
      [title] => 
    )
    [uid] => 1
    [filename] => cpon.jpg
    [filepath] => sites/default/files/cpon_0.jpg
    [filemime] => image/jpeg
    [filesize] => 4434
  )
)
```

Is there a function that, using the above information, can output an image?
Is there any other method to output an image using the above information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [theme('image')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

Supposing that `$img` contains the PHP object you reported, then the following code can be used to output the image.

```
$output = theme('image', $img->filepath); // Drupal 6.
$output = theme('image', array('path' => $img->filepath)); // Drupal 7.
```

Comment: why you put the the image parameter in the theme(). not using theme_image(). thank you.

Comment: Because that is the way to call theme functions. Theme functions can be altered from modules, which can (for example) implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) to associate `theme_mymodule_image_output()` with the 'image' theme ID. If you use `theme('image')`, Drupal will invoke any theme function that is associated with 'image'; if you call `theme_image()`, you don't allow to any module to overwrite the output. Theme functions are thought to allow modules to alter the output produced by others.

Comment: I am getting "Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_attributes() must be an array, string given" with this code...

Comment: @giorgio79 The code was for Drupal 6; I have updated my answer.

Comment: I had to use theme('image_style', ...) and I had to include the parameter 'style_name' => 'xxx' in the properties array in order to get this to work.  (D7)

Answer (score 4):

file field has theme function in *filefield_formatter.inc:117*

```
/**
 * Theme function for the 'generic' single file formatter.
 */
function theme_filefield_file($file) {
  //
}

foreach($node->field_image AS $image){
  print theme('file_field', $image); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [`theme('image', $path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/6), you can also use [`theme('imagecache', $presetname, $path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE)`](http://api.lullabot.com/theme_imagecache) if you use the [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, using `theme_image()`.